# regex help - python - extract all image url from css

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am trying to extract all the image (.jpg, .png, .gif) uri's from css files.

Sample css

```
.blockpricecont{width:660px;height:75px;background:url('../images/postBack.jpg') 
repeat-x;/*background:url('../images/tabdata.jpg') repeat-x;*/border: 1px solid #B7B7B7;
```

regex used -

```
  images = re.compile("(?:\()(?:'|\")?(.*\.jpg('?))", flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

The problem is, there are few css classes with commented code in it (/* ---- */) and these comments contain .jpg reference. The output I am getting for the above regex is

```
output
 ["../images/postBack.jpg') repeat-x;/*background:url('../images/tabdata.jpg'"]

expected output:
 ["../images/postBack.jpg"]
```

I want my regex to stop at the first match of .jpg but its continuing till the end of the line.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
print re.findall('url\(([^)]+)\)',target_text)
```

I think that should work

Comment: its just matching anything inside url() and returning it .. since the only time you use url is for images... it should just return you a list of images ...

Comment: A slight improvement on a great regex: `url = re.compile(r'url\(["\']?(?P<url>[^"\']+)["\']?\)')`. That way writing `re.search(url, some_css).group('url')` returns the url.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way would be to eliminate comments before matching:

```
css = re.sub(r'(?s)/\*.*\*/', '', css)
```

However, I do agree with Matthew that using a dedicated parser would be better. Here's an example with [tinycss](http://packages.python.org/tinycss):

```
import tinycss

def urls_from_css(css):
    parser = tinycss.make_parser()
    for r in parser.parse_stylesheet(css).rules:
        for d in r.declarations:
            for tok in d.value:
                if tok.type == 'URI':
                    yield tok.value

for url in urls_from_css(css):
    print url
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe, this way, first strip comments with re.sub then re.findall the goodies.

```
example_css = """.blockpricecont{width:660px;height:75px;background:url('../images/postBack.jpg') 
repeat-x;/*background:url('../images/tabdata.jpg') repeat-x;*/border: 1px solid #B7B7B7;"""


import re

css_comments_removed = re.sub(r'\/\*.*?\*\/', '', example_css)

pattern = re.compile(r"(\'.*?\.[a-z]{3}\')")
matches = pattern.findall(css_comments_removed)
for i in matches:
    print(i)
```

prints

```
'../images/postBack.jpg'
```

Answer (score 0):

This would probably be better suited to a css parser. I haven't used it, but I've seen [this one](http://cssutils.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/html/docs/parse.html#cssparser) recommended before.

Comment: probably technically ... but finding url is probably ok with regex

Comment: @JoranBeasley I agree, but I thought it was worth saying.

Comment: thanks Matthew. I have to parse .php pages too looking out for uri's. I said css here just to keep it simple. Thanks anyway.